# How to copy a column without duplicate values? SQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I'm looking to copy the values of two columns (Column 1, Column 2, and Column 3) to another table; however, I don't want values to be copied if there is a duplicate value in Column 2. An example is below:

```
UserID     Item    Date
------------------------
101        1   <  2-10-2016
101        1   <  2-9-2016
101        2      2-11-2016
101        3      2-11-2016
102        5      2-11-2016
102        6      2-14-2016
103        1      2-11-2016
103        4   <  2-11-2016
103        4   <  2-11-2016
```

I want to INSERT INTO only:

- UserID 101 Item 1 w/ date
- UserID 101 Item 2 w/ date
- UserID 101 Item 3 w/ date
- UserID 102 Item 5 w/ date
- UserID 102 Item 6 w/ date
- UserID 103 Item 1 w/ date
- UserID 103 Item 4 w/ date

I've tried finding a way to filter duplicate Items (GROUP BY) from the table to no avail. Is there any efficient way to do this without using loops?

There is also a unique identifier column that indexes these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a  `GROUP BY UserId, Item` and use `HAVING` to determine the group population:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2)
SELECT  UserId, Item
FROM TableA
GROUP BY UserId, Item
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This will insert only non duplicated `UserId, Item` pairs into TableB.

If you want to insert **all** `UserId, Item` pairs **just once**, then use:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2)
SELECT  UserId, Item
FROM TableA
GROUP BY UserId, Item
```

Try this if you have additional fields:

```
;WITH ToBeInserted AS (
  SELECT UserID, Item, [Date], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID 
                            ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn  
  FROM TableA
)
INSERT INTO TableB (UserID, Item, [Date])
SELECT UserID, Item, [Date]
FROM ToBeInserted
WHERE rn = 1
```

[**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function is used to enumerate records that belong to the same `UserID` partition: the record having the most recent `[Date]` value has a row number equal to one, next record has row nummber = 2, etc. `INSERT` operation uses this row number value in order to select just one record from each `UserID` partition.

Comment: This is extremely helpful! What if you have a 3rd column that is simply additional information that needs to be copied as well? The logic regarding Column 1 and Column 2 still applies. I've tried running a GROUP BY UserId, Item but that doesn't work if you need to move another column. See original question please.

Answer (score 1):

Insert non-existent non-duplicate items:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2)
  SELECT T.UserId, T.Item
  FROM (
    SELECT  UserId, Item
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY UserId, Item
  ) T
  WHERE (T.UserId, T.Item) NOT IN 
    (SELECT UserId, Item FROM TableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2)
SELECT  UserId, Item, Max([Date])
FROM TableA
    GROUP BY UserId, Item
```

Use Min() if you want the smallest date to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2)
select UserId,item from TableA
group by UserId,item

Only this much gave me the desired output. Isn't it what you want.